# Send data from script from partial to controller angular

Tags: angularjs

I have this code in a partial

```
<script>
function process_wb(wb,$scope) {
  if(use_worker) XLS.SSF.load_table(wb.SSF);
  var output = "";
  console.log(wb);
  salida=to_json(wb);
}
</script>
<button  ng-click="insertar(salida)">INSERTAR</button>
```

on the controller

```
$scope.insertar = function(datos) {
  console.log('datos');
  console.log(datos);
}
```

but when i do click the function don't have any data...

any solution? Thanks for you time

Comment: Can you check your example code? What you've listed would never work - `insertar(salida)` is not going to call that `process_wb()` function.

Comment: the data exist, but when i send to controller, no data apear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inline function (inside the `<script>` tag) is assigning a variable that you are then attempting to use in the Angular click event. This will not work as you've already discovered.

Your salida variable needs to be bound to the active scope, which will then correctly map to the function. See this basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/gaabuqf6/1/

If you intend to pass data back from outside of the Angular world, you can do so by manually attaching to the active Angular scope or through traditional event handling.

For your purposes, the most straightforward would be to attach to the scope, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/j5q1xejw/2/

Comment: the data from salida is in the html, the controller is in another file, i ned to send data to the controller but it dont work thanks for your reply

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can't simply pass a javascript variable into an Angular directive as you have tried above. The variables you pass as arguments must all be attached to the scope.

Comment: but i can scope a variable?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. You can add a variable to the scope using the method I outlined above.

Comment: Man in don't have seen the latest update it works, thak you very much

Comment: Glad to have helped :)